# Angular 2 - Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401

Tags: angular, cors, preflight

I know there a already lot of same solved issues here,
but unfortunately none of them helped me :-(.
Here my problem: 
I try to connect from my localhost to my REST service on a server. It works fine with a FF REST plugin, but my application results in following errors:

- OPTIONS http://.../my_REST_Service/ 401 (Unauthorized)
- XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://.../my_REST_Service/. 
  Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401

How I try to get the data I want:

```
@Injectable()
export class ModelsComponent implements OnInit {

    private restRoot = 'http://.../my_REST_Service';
    private data;

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getModels().subscribe(res => {
            this.data = res; 
            console.log(this.data);
        });
    }

    authHeaders() {
        let username: string = 'xxxx';
        let password: string = 'xxxx';

        let token: string = btoa(username + ":" + password);

        let headers: Headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Authorization');
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + token);
        headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200/");
        headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
        headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept,Accept-Charset,Accept-Encoding,Accept-Language,Authorization,Connection,Content-Type,Cookie,DNT,Host,Keep-Alive,Origin,Referer,User-Agent,X-CSRF-Token,X-Requested-With");
        headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

        return headers;
    }

    getModels(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(this.restRoot, {
                    headers: this.authHeaders(), 
                    withCredentials: true        <- from a similar issue
               }).map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

My Server is configured like this:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:4200"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Accept,Accept-Charset,Accept-Encoding,Accept-Language,Authorization,Connection,Content-Type,Cookie,DNT,Host,Keep-Alive,Origin,Referer,User-Agent,X-CSRF-Token,X-Requested-With"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"   
Header set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Authorization"       <- from a similar issue
```

I know there are other same/ similar solved issues. But I still do not know what to do or how to do it.
I really appreciate it if someone can help me with my code!!

Comment: Don't put Access-Control headers in your request! They are **response** headers!

Answer (score 4):

The browser does an `OPTIONS` request before doing your `HttpGet`, you need to add an endpoint with the same route as the `HttpGet`, make that an `HttpOptions` request, remove auth from that endpoint and return a `200 OK` from it and that should fix your issue.

Comment: Not Angular is doing the OPTIONS request but the browser.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am not sure if I get you right. 
Do I have to make a HttpOptions request without auth in my Angular code or have I remove the auth from the REST Endpoint?
The problem is that the used REST-API require a valid user to be authenticated by default and it is not possible to remove auth from that.
Or did I misunderstand your answer completely?

Comment: You need to create a REST endpoint for HttpOptions. It will be exactly the same route as your other endpoint, only the http verb will be `HttpOptions`. This endpoint will just return a status 200 Ok response. This endpoint should allow anonymous auth as the options request does not contain authorization.

Comment: Ok, thats not possible then. 
I use a fix REST service with multiple endpoints. Maybe I find a way to completely turning off the authorization.

Answer (score 4):

"My Server is configured like this" — That's mostly irrelevent. Look at the error message: "Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401"

It says nothing about any of the things you mentioned with Access-Control-Allow-Thing.

- The browser is making an OPTIONS request to ask if a cross origin request is allowed.
- The response says "Your username and password is wrong".

Since the browser hasn't received permission to make the cross origin request: **It hasn't sent a username and password**.

You need to find the code on your server that performs the authorisation and **exclude OPTIONS requests** from that test. Anybody should be able to make the OPTIONS request, not just people who have the username and password.

Comment: Do you think excluding OPTIONS requests could be a security concern in some cases?

Comment: @KyleVassella — Only if you respond to them inappropriately (e.g. by treating them like a POST request and storing data in the database).

Answer (score 1):

On the server side, if using Node.js you can consider authorizing all OPTIONS requests so browsers won't need authentication to check what methods are authorized on the server/REST API.

Consider code like:

```
if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.status(200).end();
} else {
    next();
}
```